# How would I go about pushing one view controller to another view controller that doesn't have a nib file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

How would I go about pushing `oneviewcontroller` to another `viewcontroller` that doesn't have a nib file?

this is what I'm currently doing. There is no nib file for `UserViewController` though and yet I'm still using `initWithNibName:@"UserViewController"`

```
-(IBAction)userProfile:(id)sender {

    UserViewController *userViewController = [[UserViewController alloc]
                                                            initWithNibName:@"UserViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:userViewController animated:YES ];

    [userViewController release];  

}
```

thanks for any help!!!

Comment: When there is no nib file then you should not provide nib name.You can push view controller as follows:UserViewController *userViewController = [[UserViewController alloc] init]; and create views programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any nib file you should not mention any. Please find below code :

```
-(IBAction)userProfile:(id)sender {

UserViewController *userViewController = [[UserViewController alloc]
                                                        init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:userViewController animated:YES ];

[userViewController release];  

}
```

You can place `-(id)init` method in **UserViewController** and set global variables.

Answer (score 3):

You just use:

```
[[UserViewController alloc] init];
```

You can build the corresponding views in the `loadView` method. 
But check the [View Controller Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html) from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)userProfile:(id)sender {

UserViewController *userVC = [[UserViewController alloc] init];

// Replace the current view controller
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self navigationController] viewControllers]];
[viewControllers removeLastObject];
[viewControllers addObject:userVC];
[[self navigationController] setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
}
```